# CSS - Can an image overlap a page border without affecting page width?

Tags: html, css

I have the following element in my initial page concept:

http://tinyurl.com/bcmcxp9

The ribbon is a PNG image. What I'd like to be able to do is position this image exactly over the border of a box-shadowed div (representing the page content), without affecting the page width.

I've tried a couple of techniques.

By using position:absolute, I've been able to achieve the visual effect I was looking for, but it brings up the dreaded horizontal scrollbars! I want the edge of the **div** (not the edge of the image) to represent the edge of the page.

```
#banner-ribbon {
    background-image: url(ribbon-right.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute:
    width: 419px;
    height: 114px;
    left: 700px;
    top: 400px;
}
```

By using a div that sits between the content wrapper and the background, I've been able to position the image in the right place without affecting the horizontal scrollbars (sort of, I might need a little javascript to absolute-position it relative to the center), but I can't raise the image's z-index above its child divs!

```
#banner-ribbon-wrapper {
    background-image: url(ribbon-right.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 90% 400px;
    z-index: 70; /* does nothing */
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You must have a `position` other than `static` ( which is the default position ) for the z-index to apply.

Comment: To improve your question you could use jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the image is extending the boundaries of the page, causing the horizontal scroll bars. One way to fix this may be to set a width for your page and then hide anything that goes outside of it. Something like this may work for you:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8GByr/)

Comment: I'd actually come up with my own solution, but this one is better.
I created a full-screen overlay div as a **sibling** instead of a parent. 

`#banner-ribbon-wrapper {
    background-image: url(ribbon-right.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 90% 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height 100%;
    z-index: 70; /* works now that the div is a sibling and not a parent */
}`

However, unlike Zhihao's solution, I still have to worry about centering the background image, and I've found that overlay divs break CMS editors like Weebly. Zhihao, yours works great!

Answer (score 0):

Give your content div

```
position: relative
```

and to your ribbon

```
position: absolute
right:0
```

Make sure your image don't extend boundaries uncontrollably.

Working sample on JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BrvJk/

Comment: This aligns the ribbon against the right edge of the content div, but it doesn't make the image overlap the boundary of the content div.